# Handle errors with POST call in Redux-Saga

Tags: post, error-handling, react-redux, redux-saga, yield

My API returns a JSON as a response if the error is internal server (code: 500 ). Below is the code I am using. I'm able to get the error ( Error 500: Internal Server Error ), but can't seem to get the JSON in the response. Please help.

```
    try{
    const items = yield call(request, url, postOptions);
    if (items.status >= 200 && items.status < 300) {
      const jsonResponse = yield items.text()
      yield put(itemsLoaded(jsonResponse))
    }
    else throw items; 

  } catch (err) {
    yield put(itemsLoadingError(err));
  }
```